# How is the checksum in apex_util.prepare_url() calculated?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

I'm currently reviewing an apex application which uses a "APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL" call with "p_checksum_type => 3" to return an URL with a valid 'SESSION' level checksum argument.

An example of such a generated URL would be:

```
https://localhost/APEX/f?p=PAGE:APP:SESSION::::P1337_AID,P1337_ALID:2,&cs=3qGcLriwAHNz36flGhBsxJewK0yWV38ac1cn4GcwDe3r0TZ3GKLtyKSbgLwTCE_kd6YSSpHwh7HlWL-rrfvy36z
```

My Question is how the &cs URL argument value is internally generated. The documentation isn't very helpful in this case. Thanks in advance.

Apex version: 21.1.2

Apex documentation for prepare_url:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/PREPARE_URL-Function.htm#AEAPI160

Comment: I don't think that that information is public - it's a potential security risk. What is the business problem you're trying to solve ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie It's just a case study if they are secure

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to reverse engineer their checksum algorithm, there's several hash functions available to be aware of; see [section "3.3.2.1.8 Selecting a Checksum Hash Function"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeadm/configuring-service-level-security-settings.html#GUID-B4019F56-044F-4E56-89D0-EF911395FDDF) in the Administration Guide:

> From Checksum Hash Function, select a hash function that Application Express uses to generate one way hash strings for
> checksums.
>
> The SHA-2 algorithms are only supported on Oracle Database 12c or
> later. **Most Secure** automatically selects the most secure algorithm
> available. Therefore, Oracle recommends this setting. On Oracle
> Database 12c or later, this evaluates to SHA-2, 512 bit and on Oracle
> Database 11g, SHA-1 is the most secure algorithm. Since the MD5
> algorithm is deprecated, Oracle does not recommend this setting.

[The descriptions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmdb/preventing-url-tampering.html#GUID-0A640D92-3FB2-410E-ACC8-1464F2F632FE) of the 3 different levels of session state protection (Application Level, User Level, Session Level) vaguely mention that the checksum can be specific to "the workspace and application", "the workspace, application, and user", or "the session", respectively.

Also, an [older version](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/sec_dev.htm#CHDCFCCH) of the documentation mentions that the checksums include the hidden page item `pSalt` as a salt.

Based on the underscores and dashes in the checksum text, they're probably using `base64url` to convert the binary hash (64 bytes for SHA-256) to a text value (~87 characters for SHA-256).

Now, what specific fields are they running the checksum on? No idea, that's the real question. Hope that's enough to point you in the right direction!